# Can someone transliterate this artist's name?

Tags: translation, names

This is a placard next to a work of art from a museum in Japan. I'm curious as to what it says—particularly, what the artist's name is.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful calligraphy, but voted to close per policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The artist's name is Mitsuo Banba (番場 三雄).
The title of the painting is ヤルンツァンポ渡る "Crossing the Yarlung Tsangpo".

[Yarlung Tsangpo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarlung_Tsangpo_River) is the part of the Brahmaputra River that flows through Tibet.